# Mock class in class under test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, mockito, robolectric

How I can mock with Mockito other classes in my class which is under test?

For example:

MyClass.java

```
class MyClass {
    public boolean performAnything() {
        AnythingPerformerClass clazz = new AnythingPerformerClass();
        return clazz.doSomething();        
    }
}
```

AnythingPerformerClass.java

```
class AnythingPerformerClass {
    public boolean doSomething() {
        //very very complex logic
        return result;
    }
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void testPerformAnything() throws Exception {
    MyClass clazz = new MyClass();
    Assert.assertTrue(clazz.performAnything());
}
```

Can I spoof `AnythingPerformerClass` for excluding unnecessary logic from `AnythingPerformerClass`? Can I override `doSomething()` method for simple return `true` or `false`?

Why I specify Mockito, because I need it for Android testing with Robolectric.

Comment: Why do you instantiate one instance of the class for each method call? That looks seriously overkill

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could refactor `MyClass` so that it uses [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Instead of having it create an `AnythingPerformerClass` instance you could pass in an instance of the class to the constructor of `MyClass` like so :

```
class MyClass {

   private final AnythingPerformerClass clazz;

   MyClass(AnythingPerformerClass clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   public boolean performAnything() {         
     return clazz.doSomething();        
   }
}
```

You can then pass in the mock implementation in the unit test

```
@Test
public void testPerformAnything() throws Exception {
   AnythingPerformerClass mockedPerformer = Mockito.mock(AnythingPerformerClass.class);
   MyClass clazz = new MyClass(mockedPerformer);
   ...
}
```

Alternatively, if your `AnythingPerformerClass` contains state then you could pass a `AnythingPerformerClassBuilder` to the constructor.

Comment: According to the [Mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2), the default return value for a primitive `boolean` will be `false`, so this test case fails.

Comment: Well, I omitted the step where the method call is mocked out. The OP says "Can I override doSomething() method for simple return true or false?" So I don't think I should constrain the code.

Answer (score 3):

As it currently is (both declaration and instantiation of the `AnythingPerformerClass` inside a method, it's not possible to mock the `AnythingPerformerClass` using only Mockito.

If possible, move both the declaration and the instantiation of `AnythingPerformerClass` to the class level: declare an instance variable of type `AnythingPerformerClass` and have it instantiated by the constructor.

That way, you could more easily inject a mock of `AnythingPerformerClass` during test, and specify its behaviour. For example:

```
when(anythingPerformerClassMock.doSomething()).thenReturn(true);
```

or to test error handling:

```
when(anythingPerformerClassMock.doSomething()).thenTrow(new NullPointerException());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set what to return in Mockito.

```
when(mock.method()).thenReturn(someValue)
```

Comment: Will not work, even if you mock both classes in same test, mockito will fail to infer that outer class is expected to use mocked object.